# How to simplify this json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

Is there a better way to build this (3 levels) hash ? Data come from an ActiveRecord query

```
[{"currency"=>"EUR", "year"=>2017, "month"=>10, "payments"=>112, "payments_received"=>9, "total_amount"=>"350.8"}, {"currency"=>"USD", "year"=>2017, "month"=>10, "payments"=>30, "payments_received"=>9, "total_amount"=>"352.48"}, {"currency"=>"EUR", "year"=>2017, "month"=>11, "payments"=>18, "payments_received"=>3, "total_amount"=>"121.68"}, {"currency"=>"USD", "year"=>2017, "month"=>11, "payments"=>38, "payments_received"=>16, "total_amount"=>"1745.04"}]
```

```
 payments.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |k,v| k[v] = Hash.new{ |k,v| k[v] = Hash.new{ |k,v| k[v] = {} } } }) do |h,memo| 
   memo[h['currency']][h['year']][h['month']] = h.except('currency', 'year', 'month')
 end
```

Comment: I would use ActiveModel::Serializers or Jbuilder.

Comment: thanks @max. I learn more about those ones.